# Is there a way to drag and drop nodes into or out of other nodes in Cytoscape js?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cytoscape.js

i'm looking for a way to drag node/s out of its compound node and drop it to another node (which will then its new parent).

The example shows some captured nodes in compound nodes. But i found no way to "free" them by dnd.

http://jsbin.com/gist/5b192c88616af2f75344?output

I missing also some HTML5 events like dragover, dragout and such things. Is there a way to get it?

I tried to use the given cytoscape js events to "move" some nodes, but without a good user experience.

Answer (score 5):

Based on maxkfranz's answer this approach will allow for adding a parent to a node by dragging into it. 
Bind a tapend event (fires when released) to orphan nodes (those without parents) in which you detect if the mouse cursor is in the bounding box of a parent node.

```
//dragging orphan nodes into parents
cy.on('tapend', ':orphan', function(event){
    var node = event.cyTarget;
    var mouse = event.cyRenderedPosition;

    cy.$(':parent').each(function(i, ele){
        //ensure we dont drag into self
        if (ele !== node){
            //check if we dragged into a compound node
            var pos = ele.renderedBoundingBox();
            if (mouse.x > pos.x1 && mouse.x < pos.x2){
                if (mouse.y > pos.y1 && mouse.y < pos.y2){
                    console.log("Move ", node.id(), " into ", ele.id());
                    node.move({
                        parent: ele.id()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You may want to use a forEach loop instead and break the loop after node.move(), just in case of overlapping nodes and a slight performance increase.

Comment: instead of `event.cyTarget` and `event.cyRenderedPosition` i had to use `event.target` and `event.position` but this work actually pretty fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape.js allows you to build your own gestures by emitting custom events.  It's pretty straightforward to create your own `dragover` etc. events on top of `drag` and `ele.boundingBox()`.  You can structure your gesture and custom event into an [autoscaffolded](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/autoscaffolding) [extension](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) for more reusability, if you like.  If you do make an extension, please consider submitting it to [the list](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) so other devs can benefit from it and contribute to it.

The core library has to be kept performant, which precludes doing expensive `dragover` checks.  Otherwise, core usecases for other devs would be negatively affected.

Your custom gesture can make certain assumptions -- that the core lib couldn't --  to keep things faster.  For example, if you care only about compound parent nodes for `dragover` etc. events, then you can do bounding box checks only for parents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im looking for an concrete answer how to solve my problem. When i drag an element e1 over another element e2, e2 wont throw an dragover event. I looking forward to an example to build someting like this: [link](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/regrouping.html)